# The count of shared_ptr changes for each run

Tags: c++

In the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr example:

Although the constructor and destructor is called only once, why means the shared_ptr is thread safe. But why the count changes from 4, 5, 6. Thanks for any suggestion.

***lp.get() = 0x2299b30, lp.use_count() = 4/5/6***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
 
struct Base
{
    Base() { std::cout << "  Base::Base()\n"; }
    // Note: non-virtual destructor is OK here
    ~Base() { std::cout << "  Base::~Base()\n"; }
};
 
struct Derived: public Base
{
    Derived() { std::cout << "  Derived::Derived()\n"; }
    ~Derived() { std::cout << "  Derived::~Derived()\n"; }
};
 
void thr(std::shared_ptr<Base> p)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::shared_ptr<Base> lp = p; // thread-safe, even though the
                                  // shared use_count is incremented
    {
        static std::mutex io_mutex;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(io_mutex);
        std::cout << "local pointer in a thread:\n"
                  << "  lp.get() = " << lp.get()
                  << ", lp.use_count() = " << lp.use_count() << '\n';
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> p = std::make_shared<Derived>();
 
    std::cout << "Created a shared Derived (as a pointer to Base)\n"
              << "  p.get() = " << p.get()
              << ", p.use_count() = " << p.use_count() << '\n';
    std::thread t1(thr, p), t2(thr, p), t3(thr, p);
    p.reset(); // release ownership from main
    std::cout << "Shared ownership between 3 threads and released\n"
              << "ownership from main:\n"
              << "  p.get() = " << p.get()
              << ", p.use_count() = " << p.use_count() << '\n';
    t1.join(); t2.join(); t3.join();
    std::cout << "All threads completed, the last one deleted Derived\n";
}
// Output
Base::Base()
  Derived::Derived()
Created a shared Derived (as a pointer to Base)
  p.get() = 0x2299b30, p.use_count() = 1
Shared ownership between 3 threads and released
ownership from main:
  p.get() = 0, p.use_count() = 0
local pointer in a thread:
  lp.get() = 0x2299b30, lp.use_count() = 5
local pointer in a thread:
  lp.get() = 0x2299b30, lp.use_count() = 3
local pointer in a thread:
  lp.get() = 0x2299b30, lp.use_count() = 2
  Derived::~Derived()
  Base::~Base()
All threads completed, the last one deleted Derived
```

Comment: why means -> which means

Comment: You can always [edit] your question.

Comment: Short answer: The output is dependent on how threads are scheduled. No wonder then that it is different in different runs. As an exercise, you can try to find out possible run paths that produce individual use counts.

Answer (score 2):

> But why the count changes from 4, 5, 6.

Because you have 6 copies of shared pointer, each function `thr()` has 2 - parameter `p` and local copy `lp`. Using `thr()` with 3 threads makes it 3x2==6. If not pause of 1 second in beginning of the function theoretically it is possible you get count of 7 - if all thread would start before `main()` releases it's `p`, but that is unlikely to happen. Then when threads continue to execute and release copy `lp` and then `p` when function terminates that count decreasing until all of them finished and all copies dies, counter reaches 0 and controlled object destroyed.

Comment: Thanks ^-^, I forget there is an copy in the function's parameter